# Mysql 5.5 dump and mysql 5.6 import

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have dumped database from MySQL 5.5 having EST timezone and while importing to MySQL 5.6 UTC timezone, the values of timestamp columns are changing by +05:00.

Please guide me how to import data without adding +05:00 hourse to the new timezone.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [--tz-utc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tz-utc) flag will do the trick.

Comment: on EST server:

mysqldump --skip-tz-utc -u root -p db1 > /bkp1.sql

on UTC server, also changing database/schema name:

mysql -u root -p -h localhost new_db2 </bkp1.sql